How can I disable the gray hints in Rider?

I recently began using Rider in conjunction with Visual Studio and have been unable to locate a setting that would disable the grayed-out prompts.I have reviewed the settings, however, as I am unaware of the specific function in question, I have been unable to locate the desired option.

Before people comment "Post code, not images of code" - it's about the syntax highlighting - so we actually need the image!

Is the "AI Assistant" enabled? If so, try to disable that plugin. Not sure if it's that, however.

Can confirm that this is either the AI Assistant, or the full line completion is becoming overzealous.

In File | Settings | Editor | General | Inline Completion, disbale both Full Line completion and Cloud completion suggestions there.
